# Gatsby PWA How to handle updates?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, gatsby

I am using the `gatsby-plugin-offline` plugin and would like to know if there is a way to handle updates.

I would like to display a message if a new version is available like
https://medium.com/progressive-web-apps/pwa-create-a-new-update-available-notification-using-service-workers-18be9168d717

At the moment I need to hard reload the site in order to see changes.

How to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do that, Gatsby v2 supports `onServiceWorkerUpdateFound` on `gatsby-browser.js`, check this for more details: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/9087#issuecomment-429853664